# Starting nested loop from current element position to the end of the list

Tags: python, text-processing

I have a text file with the following structure:

```
name1:
sentence. [sentence. ...] # can be one or more
name2:
sentence. [sentence. ...]
```

**EDIT** Input sample:

```
Djohn:
Hello. I am Djohn
I am Djohn.
Bot:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
est laborum.
Ninja:
Hey guys!! wozzup
```

**EDIT 2** Input sample:

```
This is example sentence  that can come before first speaker.
Djohn:
Hello. I am Djohn
I am Djohn.
Bot:
Yes, I understand, don't say it twice lol
Ninja:
Hey guys!! wozzup
```

Each item (name or sentence(s) is an **Unicode** string. I put this data into list, and want to form a dictionary:

```
{
    'name1': [[sentence.], ..]
    'name2': [[sentence.], ..]
}
```

**EDIT 3**

> The dictionary I am building intended to be written into a file and it is bunch of **Unicode** strings.

What I am trying to do is this:

```python
for i, paragraph in enumerate(paragraphs): # paragraphs is the list
                                           # with Unicode strings
    if isParagraphEndsWithColon(paragraph):
        name = paragraph
        text = []
        for p in range(paragraphs[i], paragraphs[-1]):
            if isParagraphEndsWithColon(p):
                break
            localtext.extend(p)
        # this is output dictionary I am trying to build
        outputDocumentData[name].extend(text)
```

E.g. I need to make a nested loop from the found 'name:' sentence until the next one, while extending the list of sentences for the same key (which is name). 
The thing is range() don't work here for me, because it expects integers.

Looking for "pythonic" way to make nested loop from the current element to the end of the list. (feels like making slice of the list each iteration will be inefficient)

Comment: Could you add a concrete input sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

lines = ["Djohn:",
         "Hello. I am Djohn",
         "I am Djohn.",
         "Bot:",
         "Yes, I understand, don't say it twice lol",
         "Ninja:",
         "Hey guys!! wozzup"]


name = ''
result = {}
for k, v in groupby(lines, key= lambda x: x.endswith(':')):
    if k:
        name = ''.join(v).lstrip(':')
    else:
        result.setdefault(name, []).extend(list(v))

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'Djohn:': ['Hello. I am Djohn', 'I am Djohn.'], 'Ninja:': ['Hey guys!! wozzup'], 'Bot:': ["Yes, I understand, don't say it twice lol"]}
```

The idea is to group the input into name line, not name line so you use as `key lambda x: x.endswith(':')`.

Comment: Do the first line is a name?

Comment: The only problem left is that strings can be in Unicode, non ascii. Is there way to write this dictionary to a file (using .encode('utf8'))? I tried to make a loop `    for p in lines:
       p = p.encode('utf8')' but it doesn't help

Comment: >Do the first line is a name? no

Comment: Well is the first line is not a name what is the key of those groups of lines? What Python version are you using?

Comment: python3. It looks like it groups it with empty key, which in general is okay for me, I can filter it after.

Comment: So you want to write the dictionary to a file? What have you tried? What is the format you want to write?

Comment: I tried this: `for l in lines: l = l.encode('utf8')` before code with grouping, but it didn't work (the test print to the terminal of a resulting dictionary was containing characters in form: \u0554 etc.). Anyway, I think I will write each string into a file just looping on a dictionary values and calling .encode each time. Hopefully it will work

Comment: If I am not mistaken, that should not be a problem when you write the file.